# Adding text after and before the div

Tags: jquery, css

How to add text before and after a `div` element?. I tried with the pseudo selectors `before` and `after`, but it not work.

```
.volume-container:before {
    content: 'Storage';
}

.volume-container:after {
    content: '25% Usage';
}
```

I want to add a text before and after my volume control as like storage control where the pseudo selectors work.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrynu

Comment: You realise that your linked demo doesn't have an element of class 'volume-container'? You do have a `.container` though, did you mean to use that?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrynu the code has .volume-container and yes i did mean to use it.

Comment: The linked codepen resource does not match the code included in the question. The question itself should contain sufficient code for reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`::before` and `::after` are not intended to actually insert content *outside* of the element, [but inside, as the *first* and *last* children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3abefore).

However, changing your pen to actually use `.volume-container:before` and `.volume-container:after`, [your content is visible](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gosfz). Whether you wish it to visually look as it does is another question, but I guess that my explanation above might indicate why it's not working as intended.

Comment: Thanks Ian, is there anyway we can fix it and bring text before and after the volume stack?.

Comment: How do you *want it to look*. Try not using a pseudo-element to show me, and I can try to help :)

Comment: OK, well that looks fine as it is, why would you want to add the pseudos to `.volume-container` specifically?

Comment: I was just trying to add text before and after so went with pseudo selector. I am fine with any way to bring that text before and after.

Comment: Well if you really want to have some pseudos on `#storage` and `.pb1` (add an ID, and try to be clear, like `#volume-progress`...) then you'll need to fix up your widths. Try to take a step back and get a clear idea of how things should be laid out and then tackle your problem :)